# Record multiple tracks from multiple audio sources at once

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

I’m looking for a software that is able to record multiple audio sources at once in realtime. I have three sound sources (two sound cards, and one loopback source) I want to record from and mix them together at a *later* point. As such a stereomix or similar approach that mixes the sources before recording is not an option. I want to keep all sources separate for as long as possible, and preferably synchronized as well.

Is there anything that is able to do this? Adobe Soundbooth (at least in the version I own) only allows mixing them in the beginning, and Audacity only supports recording one source at a time as well (multiple instances have the recording disabled).

Comment: Have you seen this page?  http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Multichannel_Recording  Audacity seems to support this with certain hardware.

Comment: Audacity can only record multiple channels, but not from multiple devices. And I don’t really want to buy new hardware just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking some more, and testing quite a few different programs, I found [n-Track Studio](http://ntrack.com/) which does the job very well. It can handle an arbitrary number of input devices, and allows you to record from them simultaneously. The recorded tracks are then saved separately as .wav or whatever you want.

It does not seem to support much post processing, but as a simple recording tool it works really well. And you can always do the post processing in Audacity, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

[Alis](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alis/) can do this if all you want is to record. It does not have many options though (e.g. sample rate).