# Get the Pre-Mix audio streams from windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, audio-recording, multi-channel

I have been searching but I have not found anything that describes what I am looking for.

I would like to record audio from multiple running programs in windows but I don't want the final mix, I would like to get each program's [audio session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a separate file, or as a separate channel in a multichannel audio file.

[Everything I have searched for](https://superuser.com/questions/398911/record-multiple-tracks-from-multiple-audio-sources-at-once) only offers recording from multiple simultaneous **hardware** sources, however I am looking for something that can record multiple simultaneous **software** sources. Does what I am looking for exist, or is it not possible with the way the sound API in windows works?

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing your own device driver, the closest thing I can find is to use a virtual audio cable solution (many alternatives exist) to have each app play back to a separate device. Then you can handle each app's data separately.

Also, you can use PulseAudio if you've the source code to the apps you need to capture, as it has per-stream monitor.